# JavaScript Regex Lookahead for .spec Files

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to omit .spec.js files and delete just .js files. I have this but it's not working:

```
(?!.*\.spec\.js$)*.js')
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "spec" is short enough that you could do something like `/[^s][^p][^e][^c]\.js/`, but it simpler to 2-pass the result: finding all ".js" ones, then filtering out any with "spec.js"

Comment: Using Node.js? Can you add complete code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `positive lookahead` to see if `.spec` is present before `.js` and filter it out accordingly. This regex will match only `.exec.js` files.

**Regex:** `.*?(?=\.spec).*?\.js`

**Explanation:**

- `.*?` matches the file name.
- `(?=\.spec)` will negatively look behind if there is `.spec` present. If yes then whole match will be discarded.
- `.*?\.js` matches the rest of file-name and `.js` extension at the end.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hV1lF4/2)**

---

**Alternatively** without using `lookahead`.

**Regex:** `.*?(\.spec).js`

**Explanation:**

- `.*?` matches initial filename.
- `(\.spec)` matches `.spec` if it's present.
- `.js` extension.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hV1lF4/3)**

Comment: @PoulBak: Thanks for reminding me that. I totally missed that fact. Will change it now.

P.S: Updated my answer using positive lookahead.

Comment: Those question marks after the asterisks don't add any value in javascript regex.

Comment: @JonAnderson: I guess you are right in this case. I added them to be on safer side to match only the wanted part and not be greedy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't this it's possible to get all the *.js files while omitting the *.spec.js files in a single regex expression without lookbehind. Alternatively you could just use two calls to endsWith():

```
filename.endsWith('.js') && !filename.endsWith('.spec.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can also use a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

`/.*(?<!spec)\.js/`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vi5oxZ/1)